# Disable scroll in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a simple demo-page for my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vvgv93k0/2/

As you can see it consists of an `iframe` and a simple `p`:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
 <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium do
```

What i would like to prevent is, that when the user clicks into the iframe, and then scrolls, the iframe is scrolled.

I want that only the main page is scrolled!

I tried to make my iframe not selectable with:

```
      -webkit-user-select: none;
```

But that somehow didnt worked! 
Wht can i do so that the scroll is never perfromed in the iframe? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your css:

```
iframe{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

set iframe as :

```
<iframe src="http://bing.com" class="foo" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

scrolling="no"

seamless="seamless"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not allowed.  If it is... I learned something new,  But I do not think you can do that

Comment: pl. check now, i have updated my code, also overflow is not working, you can try overflow-y: hidden; instead.

Comment: yea - I think those attributes in the iframe element will work , but you can't style the actual iframe , I don't think that css you put in there will do anything at all ... again I may be wrong